# UIStoryboard git merge issues. Team development

Tags: ios, xcode, git, uistoryboard

How you solve issues with merging storyboard.

I found few suggestion:

First - using xib instead storyboard

Second - using different storyboards for different views

Third - write code UI instead using UI builder

I think all of this solutions have a chance to live.

I think storyboard is a good solution for development, but I also think that apple has made mistake created all scenes in one file. I think better way have different files for each scene that is in storyboard and if someone modified one scene it does not affect on other scene because each scene has separate file. I hope they will implement it in new SDK.

But right we have what we have and I what to ask all how you resolve merging conflict when you work as a team. Because my last experience 170 merge issues in UIStoryboard file and honestly it simple to resolve "by hand" instead of using Xcode merger =)

Thanks for all recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have storyboards inside other storyboards.

Comment: How do you do that? Never heard of such a thing.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Define a view controller class inside its own storyboard (or Xib) file, then reference it within your main storyboard.  That way people can independently work on those components with no conflicts to the main storyboard file.

Comment: I'd hardly use the word "inside" to describe this. But how does it differ from option Second given in the question (except he wrote view  but you can't put just a view in a storyboard so he must have meant view controller)